# 2006 xaml schemas no longer accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, schema

i'm currently working on a legacy application using WPF. i downloaded it from our git but when building the project i'm getting the following errors.

```
The tag 'Ribbon' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon'. 

The property 'KeyTipService.KeyTip' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.
```

i tried looking in for the links described, but they both fail with a 404
so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or later, you should add a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll`.

You will find it under Project->Add Reference->Framework->Assemblies in Visual Studio.